# Material Design Icon Fonts are not working when publish exe file of MAUI project

Tags: c#, exe, maui, material-design-icons

I used Material Design Icon Fonts for icon image in my Maui project. When I publish my project as exe file and run, icon images are not appear.

Please share me answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set **Build Action** of Material Design Icon Fonts to `MauiFont`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I set Build Action of Material Design Icon Fonts to MauiFont. And I used it according the guideline of this ( https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/custom-fonts-material-design-icons-in-net-maui-acf59c9f98fe ) .

Comment: @CherryTun Is there any error message or log?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT  This answer is right when normal project running. But I just want to send an exe file to another users instead of an MSIX , so I changed commandName 'MSIX' to 'Project' in LunchSetting.Json and I run my project but icons are not appeared.  I referenced this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsCG8tskQ84 ). Thanks for user answer.

Comment: @CherryTun I updated the answer. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

@CherryTun I tested the code in the link you provided, and it works well. Icon images are all able to display.

Here is my code implementation:

Icon Font to #Code:

```
namespace MauiApp1.Helpers 
{
      static class Icomoon
       {
            public const string Icon1 = "\ue900";
            public const string Icon2 = "\ue901";
            public const string Icon3 = "\ue916";
       }
}
```

Register the font in your MauiProgram.cs:

```
namespace MauiApp1
{
    public static class MauiProgram
   {
         public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp ()        
         {
              var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder ();
              builder.UseMauiApp<App> ()                
              .ConfigureFonts (fonts =>{
                           fonts.AddFont ("OpenSans-Regular.ttf","OpenSansRegular");
                           fonts.AddFont ("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf","OpenSansSemibold");
                           fonts.AddFont ("icomoon.ttf", "icomoon");
                        });
             ...
          }  
    }
}
```

Use it in MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Helpers" 
       x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">
       <ScrollView>
              <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" 
                                   Padding="30,0" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center">
                     <Label FontFamily="icomoon" 
                            Text="{x:Static helpers:Icomoon.Icon2}" 
                            FontSize="100"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                     <Button BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" 
                             HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                             FontSize="50" 
                             Text="follow">
                            <Button.ImageSource>
                                   <FontImageSource FontFamily="icomoon" 
                                                    Glyph="{x:Static helpers:Icomoon.Icon3}" 
                                                    Size="50"/>
                            </Button.ImageSource>
                     </Button>
              </VerticalStackLayout>
       </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

About it's not working when publish exe file of MAUI project, you can refer to this: [Publish .NET MAUI Application as Windows Executable](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7789). There are other methods to publish exe file of MAUI project
mentioned in the link. You can try it. Wish it can help you.